# Is there public iOS software interface for iPhone's FM Radio chip?

Tags: ios, iphone, fm-radio

Any live application that uses such a technique?

---

@rckoernes, @Peter M:
It has.
http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=BCM4325

---

I just wanted to know if there is any option to access it on a low-level but public way.

Comment: Since when did the iPhone have an FM radio chip?

Comment: -1 for not showing any research effort!

Comment: I've been researching for two days now. I want to emit signals from an RF transciever and read them trough BCM4325.

Comment: @Geri When Apple sells products with a feature that is a well known publicly accepted usage of the term, but you want to know something specific about a little known hardware feature that has no public interface, then it would behove you to apply a little disambiguation to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the iPhone 3GS' BCM4325 chip for bluetooth&wifi has FM radio capabilities. there actually is a guide that describes the basic but nobody has so far created an app (and required drivers, OS add ons, ...).

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=BCM4325

Comment: Interesting.  But for all intents and purposes there is no "workable" FM radio.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone does not have a FM Radio Chip.

Stating that a chip has support for something does not mean it is enabled.

Answer (score -2):

The iPhone doesn't have an FM radio.  So unless you are a time traveler from the future I think you are SOL.

The iPod nano does have an FM radio how ever.  And while it would be cool to write Apps for that hardware, again you are SOL.